# Launcher Search is showing duplicate icon

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, startup-applications, duplicate

I also have duplicates in my Dash (saw several questions about this subject). But I don't know which one I need to remove.

I went to: `/usr/share/applications`

With grep I do get the following:

```
/$ grep -R 'Startup Applications' /usr/share/applications $HOME/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-session-properties.desktop:Name=Startup Applications
/usr/share/applications/session-properties.desktop:Name=Startup Applications
```

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Is there anyone who know how I can remove the second "Startup Applications"?

Comment: Include output of this command: `grep -R 'Startup Applications' /usr/share/applications $HOME/.local/share/applications`

Comment: Do I add that to my question or in this comment? Output is:
`/$ grep -R 'Startup Applications' /usr/share/applications $HOME/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/cinnamon-session-properties.desktop:Name=Startup Applications
/usr/share/applications/session-properties.desktop:Name=Startup Applications`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are actually different. One is for Cinnamon, the other is for Unity.

To fix:

1. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/cinnamon-session-properties.desktop
   ```
2. Find this line:

   ```
   Name=Startup Applications
   ```

   Replace it with this (or similar):

   ```
   Name=Startup Applications Cinnamon
   ```
3. Save & close the file.
4. The Startup Applications should now have different names.

Comment: Thank you @minerz029, at least I do now know where it is coming from :-)

Answer (score 1):

I too had a similar issue. I had two launchers for 'System monitors' in my Ubuntu 20.04. Both the launchers appear to be having different commands to launch but launch the same software. I recognized one having 'snap' in the command line (presumably updated via snap).
I sorted it out by using the application 'menu editor', and slid the radio button of 'Hide from menus' to 'on' for the software devoid of 'snap'. Voila! I got rid of two enteries.